# WordPress content not responsive with Bootstrap custom theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a simple custom WordPress theme with Bootstrap, the problem I am having is when I use WordPress to update content, the content is not responsive as it should be.

Pictures and text are not responsive like the usual Bootstrap elements are.

I included all the CSS files.

Even when I use the text tab to manually write the HTML code in for example:

```
<p> Hi this is a sample post.......................... </p>
```

When I save and run the site, the above element is not responsive when I resize the screen.

The image I have on the site is only responsive because I linked it to the CSS class `img-responsive` from the image options in WordPress.

Any ideas why this is happening?

You can take a look at the site [here](http://chocfount.comyr.com/)

index.php source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
     <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
    <link href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/css/bootstrap.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/css/bootstrap.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>

    <![endif]-->
     <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
  </head>
  <body>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=');?>

      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>



    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>



<div style="width:100%" class="alert alert-danger"> Danger</div>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
    60%
  </div>
</div>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  <?php the_content(); ?>  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/holder.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})
    </script>
      <?php wp_footer(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the specific `p` you mention above is no longer on the site you link to, there is similar text like what's in the `h1`. They are "responsive" but you don't notice it when you have a gigantic run-on word.

For example, your `h1` or another `p`:

```
<h1>Hi There..................................................</h1>
<p>;kdsskjdhskjbfjbdsjmdbskjvdbskjbfvjmvbjmvbjvbkvjmbvjbjvnbvfnbvnbvnbvjjbvfjbfvhjlbfvjdbvkjdvbs</p>
```

In your `h1` element `There..................................................` is equal to `SomeRealyBigWordThatHasNoSpacesSoItTakesUpALotOfSpace`. Same goes for your example `p` elements.

**Answer:** If you put actual words with spacing for filler text it will wrap when you resize your browser window. Try [Lorem Ipsum text](http://www.lipsum.com/) as your placeholder copy.

Not sure if you've made it this far with Bootstrap but at some point you're probably going to need to implement the [Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).